# Svg icon display different in Chrome and Mozilla browser

Tags: css, svg

So i have icon which display different in Chrome and Mozilla. It seems like icon have some black border in Mozilla. It would help me a lot if someone knew what this is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg class="logo" width="460pt" height="399pt" viewBox="0 0 460 399" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#dc4a38ff">
<path opacity="1.00" d=" M 67.82 29.82 C 92.40 13.12 122.67 7.03 152.00 7.06 C 197.34 6.93 242.68 7.02 288.02 7.01 C 267.94 17.90 247.94 28.96 227.84 39.79 C 223.45 40.31 219.00 39.85 214.58 40.01 C 224.87 51.61 233.18 65.39 236.18 80.76 C 239.99 100.11 237.50 121.16 227.17 138.17 C 219.94 150.22 209.41 159.85 198.33 168.30 C 193.22 172.09 188.27 176.28 184.61 181.54 C 181.85 185.43 180.91 190.74 182.86 195.18 C 184.55 198.95 187.89 201.56 190.99 204.12 C 208.68 217.82 227.75 230.59 241.25 248.77 C 257.62 270.75 259.02 301.77 247.14 326.11 C 236.28 348.97 215.67 365.91 192.88 376.10 C 162.26 389.68 127.94 392.92 94.83 390.14 C 69.35 387.81 43.20 380.45 23.51 363.43 C 10.06 351.99 1.02 335.29 0.00 317.55 L 0.00 312.37 C 1.07 288.32 15.59 266.47 35.24 253.24 C 62.19 234.86 95.30 229.06 127.20 226.38 C 120.43 215.65 117.48 202.41 120.41 189.94 C 104.73 190.46 88.80 188.01 74.42 181.55 C 57.34 173.85 42.77 160.44 34.20 143.73 C 25.82 127.72 22.98 108.88 26.49 91.13 C 31.24 66.20 46.89 43.93 67.82 29.82 M 115.51 39.71 C 107.59 41.45 99.90 45.28 94.52 51.45 C 87.28 59.42 84.92 70.53 84.74 81.01 C 84.60 98.32 89.02 115.61 96.97 130.96 C 103.34 143.00 112.86 154.28 126.03 158.98 C 140.07 164.13 156.38 160.08 167.49 150.42 C 175.12 143.55 177.98 132.92 178.23 122.97 C 178.61 104.75 173.90 86.56 165.56 70.42 C 160.04 60.19 152.78 50.37 142.61 44.37 C 134.57 39.53 124.71 37.71 115.51 39.71 M 143.36 254.54 C 124.59 255.63 105.35 257.61 88.04 265.46 C 79.65 269.28 71.65 274.61 66.30 282.25 C 59.39 292.10 58.07 305.22 61.59 316.58 C 65.35 328.46 74.79 337.75 85.57 343.55 C 104.27 353.59 126.08 356.09 147.02 355.29 C 163.65 354.36 181.31 350.47 193.89 338.84 C 203.42 330.20 207.50 316.55 205.18 304.01 C 203.55 294.05 196.78 285.98 189.48 279.46 C 179.13 270.32 167.73 262.44 156.30 254.75 C 152.02 254.14 147.66 254.42 143.36 254.54 Z" />
<path opacity="1.00" d=" M 336.00 7.00 C 347.33 7.00 358.67 7.00 370.00 7.00 C 370.00 33.00 370.00 59.00 370.00 85.00 C 396.00 85.00 422.00 85.00 448.00 85.00 C 448.00 96.33 448.00 107.67 448.00 119.00 C 422.00 119.00 396.00 119.00 370.00 119.00 C 370.00 146.00 370.00 173.00 370.00 200.00 C 358.67 200.00 347.33 200.00 336.00 200.00 C 336.00 173.00 336.00 146.00 336.00 119.00 C 309.33 119.00 282.67 119.00 256.00 119.00 C 256.00 107.67 256.00 96.33 256.00 85.00 C 282.67 85.00 309.33 85.00 336.00 85.00 C 336.00 59.00 336.00 33.00 336.00 7.00 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

[image: Svg in Mozilla]

[image]

```
.logo {
    background: url(google.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    fill: #1da0f2;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, it looks fine in both browsers, can you include a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there is a faint black outline in the Chrome version also.  This makes me suspect that you are drawing two instances of the logo directly on top of one another. One black and one blue. Double check that is not the case.

There is nothing wrong with the SVG itself.

Comment: well i added svg in html too, so like you said there was two instance of svg.